# Finding XPath on Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

please help me.
Actually I want to find element locator in selenium using XPath since the id is auto-generate (the ID always changed when the page refresh). but the XPath always changed too. here is the XPath locator :

```
html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td/div/nobr
html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td/div/nobr
html/body/div[15]/div/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td/div/nobr
html/body/div[7]/div/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td/div/nobr
```

Actually I already try to use :

html/body/div[class='scrollingMenu']/div/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td/div/nobr

the div itself has unique classname scrollingMenu. but it is not working. it always give the error element not found.

Comment: Use `@attribute_name` to reference attribute using XPath : `//div[@class='scrollingMenu']/div/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td/div/nobr` . I believe the XPath can be simplified further...

Comment: Without the relevant HTML or a link to the page, I'm not sure how we are going to help you.

Comment: Hendrione, Can you please provide the HTML code for the page so that we can help you out to write the xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use element's `id` in your `XPath` as follow:

Suppose `id="constantPart-generatedPart12345"`, then `XPath` is

```
//*[contains(@id, "constantPart-")]
```

PS. If this not works, update your question with `HTML` for target element, so I can edit `XPath` appropriatelly

Answer (score 0):

Open the page in Google Chrome and use F12 to test your xPath before implementing it - has saved me a lot of time

Comment: You didn't mention how to actually do that... test the XPath.